# Avoiding nested for Loops - finding sibling records

Tags: apex, trigger, bestpractice

Background:

I have a Children object that is child of Opportunity. When a Children record gets inserted/updated i want to find if there any other sibling(children) that is set as primary children if yes then i do nothing if no sibling
is set to primary then i have to make mark the current record as primary - both on insert or update.

Comment: Is `Childrenlist` the list of all records passed in from `Trigger.new`? Or is this list of records pre-filtered in anyway?

Comment: @BobLopez Yes Childrenlist is list of records passed from trigger.new

Comment: What if there are 1 or more `Childrens__c` records in `Childrenlist` that are set to Primary, under the same parent Opportunity?

Comment: That's a good point, then if current record in trigger.new has primary checked off then code (should uncheck primary from all other records,and have only one primary child) - this piece i did not implement yet thanks for pointing it out

Comment: How will you choose which one will be the primary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use aggregate query on the child records coming into the trigger, group by the related opportunity Id with a filter on Primary field and then just run a single loop to see if there are any primary records already exist or not..

Sample Query (run this only on the oppIds based on the child records in the trigger):

```
Select OppId, Count(Id) from YourChildObject__c 
Where OppId in oppIdSet and Primary__c = true 
Group by OppId;
```

Then build a map from the aggregate result with OppId as the key and count as the value..

Sample Loop:

```
for(ChildObject child : Childrenlist){
   if(aggregateMap.get(child.OppId) < 1)
      child.Primary__c = true
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you response, just out of curiosity what approach would you recommend i should  take if i find more than one primary child?  as i want only one primary child

Comment: it depends on your business requirements.. you can block the record from saving by using record.addError method inside your trigger handler